# My scrollable div is not displaying its entire content

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I've got a huge text section that I wanted to contain in a scrollable div. I've created the scroll, and it scrolls, but the top lines of the text ve been cut off. Why is this happening? I've done scrollable divs before, albeit with less text, and it has worked fine.

The browser I'm using is Google Chrome

```css
.reglas {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.parrafo-reglas {
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="section content reglas">
  <h2>Reglas:</h2>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Los siguientes son los términos que regirán el sorteo <span>PREPARA TU FUNERAL COMO PERFUME DE GARDENIAS</span> cuyo objetivo es sortear, al público general, (2) paquetes funerarios cortesía del Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">De esta forma, <span>3 Gardenias LLC.</span> presenta oficialmente las primeras imágenes relacionadas a la película en desarrollo, <span>Perfume de Gardenias</span> y hace público el tema principal de la misma. Este sorteo apoya las gestiones para lograr
    la filmación de la película.</p>
  <h5>I. DIVULGACIÓN DEL SORTEO Y VIGENCIA</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Las reglas oficiales del sorteo <span>PREPARA TU FUNERAL</span> se rigen por el Reglamento Sobre Sorteos del Departamento de Asuntos del Consumidor del Estado Libre Asociado de Puerto Rico, aprobado el 27 de octubre de 2009.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El sorteo estará vigente a partir del 10 de julio de 2019 y termina el 30 de agosto de 2019, a la medianoche. Después de esa hora no se aceptarán más inscripciones.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Las reglas del sorteo estaran disponibles en la pagia de web de Perfume de Gradenias, www.perfumedegardenias.com, a la que se puede acceder de forma libre y atraves de la pagina del evento del sorteo en Facebook, www.facebook.com/perfumedegerdenias.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Estas reglas se encuentran redactadas únicamente en español.</p>

  <h5>II. CONDICIONES DE ELEGIBILIDAD/REGLAS DE PARTICIPACIÓN:</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Podrán ser elegibles para participar personas mayores de 18 años, en y fuera de Puerto Rico con planes de servicios fúnebres en Puerto Rico exclusivamente.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Hay tres formas de participar:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Mediante la compra en la página web del sorteo de una <span>(1) participación</span> por la cantidad de $5.00 y completar su registro de información personal. Se garantizan dos (2) opciones de pago, como algunas de las siguientes: PayPal [tarjeta
      de crédito, cuentas de bancos, etc] y ATH Móvil. Esta compra le da automáticamente <span>(1) inscripción</span> en el sorteo. Un individuo puede participar de manera ilimitada por este medio.</li>
    <li>Mediante la compra, en línea únicamente, de un <span>(1) velón</span> de diseño exclusivo para 3 Gardenias LLC, por la cantidad de $15.00 y completar su registro de información personal. Se garantizan dos (2) opciones de pago, como algunas de las
      siguientes: PayPal[tarjeta de crédito, cuentas de bancos, etc] y ATH Movil. Esta compra le da automáticamente <span>(1) inscripción</span> en el sorteo. Un individuo puede participar mediante la compra de este artículo de manera ilimitada hasta
      que el artículo se agote. En ese caso se anunciará como “AGOTADO” en la página web.</li>
    <li>Mediante la compra en línea de una <span>(1) camiseta</span> de diseño exclusivo para 3 Gardenias LLC, por la cantidad de $25.00 y completar su registro de información personal. Se garantizan dos (2) opciones de pago, como algunas de las siguientes:
      PayPal[tarjeta de crédito, cuentas de bancos, etc] y ATH Móvil. Esta compra le da automáticamente <span>(2) inscripciones</span> en el sorteo. Un individuo puede participar mediante la compra de este artículo de manera ilimitada hasta que el artículo
      se agote. En ese caso se anunciará como “AGOTADO” en la página web.</li>
    <li>También se puede participar <span>enviando por correo regular</span> en una tarjeta 3x5, nombre y apellidos, dirección postal, dirección de email, fecha de nacimiento y número de teléfono contacto a: “Prepara tu funeral como PERFUME DE GARDENIAS”,
      P.O. Box 6131, San Juan, PR 00914. La información del participante será incorporada a los boletos participantes del sorteo. 3 Gardenias LLC no se hace responsable por información ilegible o incompleta que impida identificar al concursante en cuyo
      caso se descalificará. Este medio de participación está limitado a <span>(1) participación</span> por individuo.</li>
  </ol>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Ninguno de los precios incluye el costo del envío. Las probabilidades de ganar dependen del número de participaciones recibidas.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">No serán elegibles para participar del sorteo los empleados y familia del Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc., ni ninguna de las personas vinculadas directamente con la producción de la película <span>Perfume de Gardenias</span>.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">A los ganadores, se les notificará vía llamada telefónica el día del sorteo, vía correo electrónico y, vía correo certificado en un periódo de cinco (5) días luego de entregada el acta notarial de este sorteo.</p>
  <h5>III. PREMIOS</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El sorteo ofrece dos (2) premios. El <span>primer premio</span> es un (1) Servicio Velación Tradicional del Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc.; que incluye lo siguiente:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Servicios Básicos del Director Funeral</li>
    <li>Recogido y traslado del cuerpo en el área metropolitana</li>
    <li>Embalsamamiento</li>
    <li>Otros preparativos del cuerpo</li>
    <li>Uso de facilidades de capillas</li>
    <li>Coche Fúnebre</li>
    <li>Paquete Memorial – [Incluye recordatorios, libro de firma, gratitud]</li>
    <li>Documentación</li>
    <li>Certificado de Defunción</li>
    <li>Permiso de Entierro</li>
    <li>Ataúd metal 20 gauge (colores a escoger)</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Lugar de velación podrá ser entre casa, iglesia de su preferencia o funeraria dentro de las participantes (al momento de redimirse) de la alianza del Grupo Funerario del Caribe, Inc.</li>
      <li>No incluye transportación a forense</li>
      <li>No incluye coche floral</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Este premio tiene un <span>valor estimado de entre $5,000 y $10,000.</span></p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El <span>segundo premio</span> es un (1) Servicio Cremación Biodegradable del Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc.; que incluye lo siguiente:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Servicios Básicos del Director Funeral</li>
    <li>Recogido y Traslado</li>
    <li>Cremación</li>
    <li>Bolso para cenizas</li>
    <li>Urna Biodegradable Geos</li>
    <li>Ceremonia de Disposición Básica en tierra o mar</li>
    <li>Permisos y Documentación</li>
    <ul>
      <li> Si la disposición es en mar no incluye embarcación.</li>
      <li>No incluye urna para cenizas</li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Este premio tiene un <span>valor estimado de $2,500.</span></p>
  <h5>IV. SELECCIÓN DE GANADORES Y FECHA DE SORTEO</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Se realizará un (1) sorteo, que consistirá en la selección de dos (2) boletas de participación ganadoras, que serán elegidas al azar mediante tómbola ante notari@. Los premios se adjudicarán en el siguiente orden: (i) segundo (2do) premio, y (ii) primer
    (1er) premio.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El sorteo se efectuará el martes, 3 de septiembre de 2019, a las 3:30 p.m. en Pública Espacio Cultural en Santurce.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">En la misma fecha, se seleccionarán una tercera y cuarta boleta de participación, que serán declaradas ganadoras alternas en ese mismo orden, si el ganador original de alguno de los premios no lo reclama en el término que se dispone en el Artículo VII
    de estas Reglas o es descalificado.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">3 Gardenias LLC se reserva el derecho de invalidar o descalificar las participaciones que hayan utilizado un método fraudulento o no permitido por ley para participar o que no hayan cumplido con las reglas del sorteo</p>
  <h5>V. CÓMO O DÓNDE SE PUEDEN OBTENER LAS PARTICIPACIONES/PRODUCTO PARTICIPANTE</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Las inscripciones de participación podrán obtenerse con la compra de uno de los artículos mencionados en el Artículo II de estas reglas a un costo de $5.00 por una (1) inscripción, de $15 por el artículo más una (1) inscripciones de participación o
    de $25 por el artículo más una (2) inscripciones de participación. También se podrán comprar participaciones en actividades, eventos promocionales en los que participe 3 Gardenias LLC, que se anunciarán en la página web y en redes sociales; mediante
    representantes autorizados que darán acceso a la página en línea de <a href="#" alt="perfumedegardenias.com">www.perfumedegardenias.com</a>. La información de los participantes no será compartida con terceros; se utilizará exclusivamente para propósitos
    de este sorteo y para promoción relacionada a la película.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Los artículos comprados serán entregados a los participantes en una fecha estipulada por 3 Gardenias LLC en un lugar que será divulgado en la fecha del sorteo. De no poder asistir, serán enviados por correo con un cargo adicional según aplique.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">3 Gardenias LLC no se hace responsable de artículos perdidos en tránsito postal ni por paquetes que lleguen rotos a su destino.</p>
  <h5>VI. NOTIFICACIÓN DE LOS GANADORES Y GANADORES ALTERNOS</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Una vez se efectúe el sorteo se notificará el resultado a los ganadores vía telefónica y se coordinará una cita en la oficina del Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc. en un periodo de treinta (30) días naturales, con miras a finalizar la transacción de un
    certificado válido por la cantidad y servicios establecidos en el Artículo III de estas reglas.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">En caso de no poder contactar a los ganadores, se les avisará por correo certificado con acuse de recibo a la dirección provista, para advertirles que deben coordinar una cita en la oficina del Grupo Funerario del Caribe en periodo de treinta (30) días
    naturales, contados a partir del envío de la notificación por correo. De un ganador así notificado no ponerse en contacto con 3 Gardenias LLC o el Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc. en el término advertido, quedará descalificado, y se activará el sistema
    de ganadores alternos contenido en el Artículo IV de estas reglas.</p>
  <h5>VII. VIGENCIA DE RECLAMACIÓN DE PREMIO</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Los ganadores tendrán hasta treinta (30) días a partir de la fecha de notificación para reclamar su premio. Para la reclamación de los premios no se aceptarán representantes ni apoderados. 3 Gardenias LLC se reservará el derecho de exigir otras identificaciones
    de los ganadores antes de iniciar los trámites conducentes al certificado de los premios. Ambos premios son transferibles.</p>
  <h5>VIII. INFORMACIÓN SOBRE LOS ORGANIZADORES</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Este sorteo es organizado, promocionado y llevado a cabo por 3 Gardenias LLC, corporación registrada bajo las leyes del Estado Libre Asociado de Puerto Rico para información de contacto en <a href="#" alt="perfumedegardenias.com">www.perfumedegardenias.com</a>    o escribir a <a href="mailto: perfumedegardeniaspromo@gmail.com">perfumedegardeniaspromo@gmail.com</a></p>
  <h5>IX. LISTA DE GANADORES Y GANADORES ALTERNOS</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">La lista de ganadores será publicada en la página de internet www.perfumedegardenias.com, en los perfiles en las redes sociales del sorteo <span>PREPARA TU FUNERAL como Perfume de Gardenias</span> luego de que se le comunique a los ganadores.</p>
  <h5>X. RELEVO DE RESPONSABILIDADES</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Cesará toda y cualquier obligación de 3 Gardenias LLC con los ganadores al momento de la otorgación del certificado.</p>
  <h5>XI. MODIFICACIONES DEL SORTEO</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">3 Gardenias LLC se reserva el derecho de enmendar estas reglas de ser necesario y notificar las debidas modificaciones, según lo dispuesto en el Reglamento de Sorteos del Departamento de Asuntos del Consumidor del Estado Libre Asociado de Puerto Rico,
    Reglamento 7764 de 27 de octubre de 2009.</p>
  <h5>XII. CONSENTIMIENTO</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Los ganadores concederán a 3 Gardenias LLC el derecho de difundir su imagen: nombre, fotografía, retrato, voz, firma, atributo o cualquier representación que sirva para identificar al ganador, ante un observador o escucha promedio, mediante cualquier
    procedimiento o técnica de producción, así como municipio de residencia y agencia gubernamental donde labore (en caso de que el ganador lo sea), en sus publicaciones, revistas y en la página de Internet www.perfumedegardenias.com, sin tener que compensarles
    adicionalmente al premio recibido.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El participante acuerda relevar a 3 Gardenias LLC y el Grupo Funerario del Caribe Inc., sus corporaciones subsidiarias, funcionarios, agentes, aseguradores, auspiciadores, empleados, contratistas, sucesores o causahabientes, de toda responsabilidad
    civil en daños, o de cualquier responsabilidad al amparo de la Ley 139-2011, conocida como “Ley del Derecho sobre la Propia Imagen” o cualquier otra fuente de derecho, estatal o federal, que proteja los derechos que podrían reclamarse sobre el uso
    de imágenes, fotografías, videos o audios que puedan ser obtenidos como parte de este concurso.</p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El participante acuerda permitir a 3 Gardenias LLC usar su información de contacto para enviarles futura información y material promocionando la película <span>Perfume de Gardenias.</span></p>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">El participante admite y reconoce que ha analizado estas reglas y acuerda cumplir cabalmente con estas.</p>
  <h5>XIII. PREGUNTAS, INFORMACIÓN, PARA PARTICIPAR:</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">Para dudas o preguntas puede comunicarse mediante correo electrónico a: <a href="mailto: perfumedegardeniaspromo@gmail.com">perfumedegardeniaspromo@gmail.com</a> o acceder a nuestros página en Facebook: Página Oficial de la película <a href="#" alt="perfumedegardenias.com">Perfume de Gardenias</a>    y <a href="#" alt="concurso de Perfume de Gardenias">PREPARA TU FUNERAL</a>.</p>
  <h5>XIV. HERMENÉUTICA</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">En el caso de que haya alguna inconsistencia entre la versión completa de las reglas y las reglas abreviadas, la versión que sea de más beneficio para los participantes prevalecerá.</p>
  <h5>XV. SUSPENSIÓN O CANCELACIÓN DEL SORTEO</h5>
  <p class="parrafo-reglas">3 Gardenias LLC se reserva el derecho de solicitar al Secretario del Departamento de Asuntos del Consumidor la suspensión o cancelación del sorteo, en cumplimiento con lo dispuesto en las Reglas 9, 10 y 11 del Reglamento de Sorteos del Departamento
    de Asuntos del Consumidor del Estado Libre Asociado de Puerto Rico, Reglamento 7764 de 27 de octubre de 2009.</p>
```

Comment: Please edit your code sample into a snippet that includes HTML where we can see the problem in action so it's easier to help you. Not enough info to go off of right now.